# flex-basis: Webkit / Blink ignore intrinsic aspect ratio

Tags: css, flexbox

Given a flex container

```
figure {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
}
```

and a 300x300 image with its flex-basis set at half its intrinsic width:

```
figure img {
  flex: 0 0 150px;
}
```

Chrome 41 and Safari 7 ignore the aspect ratio and display it as 150px x 300px:

[image]

Firefox 35 on the other hand keeps the intrinsic aspect ratio intact:

[image]

```css
figure {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: start;
  -moz-box-align: start;
  box-align: start;
  -webkit-align-items: flex-start;
  -moz-align-items: flex-start;
  -ms-align-items: flex-start;
  -o-align-items: flex-start;
  align-items: flex-start;
  -ms-flex-align: start;
  
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

figure img {
  -webkit-box-flex: 0;
  -moz-box-flex: 0;
  box-flex: 0;
  -webkit-flex: 0 0 150px;
  -moz-flex: 0 0 150px;
  -ms-flex: 0 0 150px;
  flex: 0 0 150px;
}

figure figcaption {
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -moz-box-flex: 1;
  box-flex: 1;
  -webkit-flex: 1 1 auto;
  -moz-flex: 1 1 auto;
  -ms-flex: 1 1 auto;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}
```

```html
<figure>
  <img src="//placekitten.com/g/300/300" />
  <figcaption>
    I'm the caption
  </figcaption>
</figure>
```

Who is correct? I believe the relevant section of the spec is [Cross-size determination](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-flexbox/#cross-sizing), but I'm having a hard time interpreting it.

Comment: I'm **guessing** Chrome/Safari is right, bc flex children aren't images anymore. They're blocks with a set height (bc contents) and now width. It is annoying though...

Comment: @Rudie, yeah, it would be annoying, because Firefox' behaviour makes much more sense to me. The part of the spec that makes me suspect you might be right though is _Determine the hypothetical cross size of each item by performing layout with the used main size and the available space, **treating auto as fit-content**_. On the other hand, in my example there's no other content to fit to - the image flex child is the one determining the flex rows height.

Comment: Seems Firefox implementation is partially correct based on [most recent spec](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-flexbox/#min-size-auto) favoring perservance of item ratio but I would expect it to resize image to 150x150 in this case.

Comment: @janfoeh What happens if you make the img an `inline-flex`? Flex children can be inline-ish, just not inline-block-ish.

Comment: @Rudie doesn't `inline-flex` apply to the container?

Comment: @janfoeh Yes, but you can make the flex children be flex containers too. So they'll be flex inline and not flex block. Maybe...

Comment: Firefox will not keep ratio if caption happens to be taller than 150px ...

Comment: @Rudie: While flex items can be flex containers, they can never be inline. `display: inline-flex` on a flex item will compute to `display: flex` instead. Items are always formatted in a flex formatting context, which is neither a block FC nor an inline FC, but behaves more like the former. Also, in response to your very first comment: `img` is a replaced element, and that shouldn't change whether it's an inline element or a flex item. For this reason, it *should* keep its intrinsic dimensions. But I'm not familiar enough with flexbox to answer this question fully.

Comment: @GCyrillus Firefox 35 and 36 do: [screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/ZAK5Uep.jpg).

Comment: I'm inclined to believe that Webkit/Blink rendering engines are in the wrong here.  I wrote a similar demo last year that's simpler (the image isn't a flex container), look at what happens when you add the object-fit property in the last example:  http://codepen.io/cimmanon/pen/Azone?editors=110

Comment: @cimmanon agreed. If I have an element with an intrinsic aspect ratio and a constraint on one dimension, I intuitively expect the other, undefined and unconstrained dimension to be sized according to the aspect ratio. Thanks for the example! What do you mean by the image being a flex container? I've only defined it as a flex child.

Comment: @TeoDragovic it seems you had the right idea all along, even if your conclusion went into the opposite direction. Kudos!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According the [editors draft](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-flexbox/) of the current Flexbox spec, **neither of these browsers are rendering this correctly**.

When I saw this question posted here, I asked about it on the www-style mailing list, and this is the [discussion it prompted](https://readable-email.org/list/www-style/topic/css-flexbox-is-intrinsic-aspect-ratio-considered-when-the-flex-basis-is-definite#content-1) (via readable-email.org):

The consensus is that a strict interpretation of the current draft would suggest that the image be sized to 300x300 pixels because that's the minimum content size of the flex item and flex items are not supposed to shrink below their minimum content size if their min-size property is `auto` (the default, and the case in your example).

Daniel Holbert (Flexbox implementor on Firefox) continued this discussion on [another thread](https://readable-email.org/list/www-style/topic/css-flexbox-min-height-on-flex-items-that-have-an-intrinsic-aspect-ratio#content-6) where he proposed that items with an intrinsic aspect ration *should* be allowed to shrink to below their minimum content size. He states:

> min-content sizes aren't really a useful lower-bound for flex items with aspect ratios. These flex items can shrink (honoring their intrinsic aspect ratio) below their min-content size, without overflowing.

Anyway, as I said, the answer to your question is that neither browser is rendering this correctly (as per the current spec), but it's possible that the spec will change to handle this case and the way Firefox is currently rendering it will be considered correct in the future.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, and more so for bringing this issue to www-style. I hope the spec will be revised according to Daniels proposal; `flex-basis` being essentially ignored in this case would be highly counterintuitive.

Comment: You're welcome. I agree that Daniel's proposal is a much better way, so I hope for the same.

Comment: If this is true, then Opera (Presto) is the only browser that does this correctly.

Comment: @cimmanon if Opera (Presto) is doing this correctly, it's doing so by accident. The spec on this issue has changed several times since Opera switched to Blink.